# What is default value for allowVolumeExpansion on the default storage class in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pvc

What is the default value for the allowVolumeExpansion?
I create my volumes through a statefulset from apiVersion: apps/v1 volumeClaimTemplates
In the case that the answer is false, how can I change it to true?

Potentially relevant info: the cluster running on GKE autopilot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out by looking into the StorageClass that your claim is using `kubectl describe StorageClass <name>`

```
volumeClaimTemplates:
- ...
  spec:
    storageClassName: <name>  # <-- check using this name
```

Recent version of GKE the default is true. More about this field can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/volume-expansion).